# Raspberry pi 4: selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python-3.7, geckodriver, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to use selenium with geckodriver on raspbian but I keep getting exceptions. I cross compiled geckodriver for arm by following [this](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/ARM.html) tutorial.

I have these versions:

- selenium **3.141.0**
- geckodriver **0.27.0**
- Python **3.7.3**
- Mozilla Firefox **68.12.0esr**

If I set `cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX` and `cap["marionette"] = False` then I get a different error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load
> the profile. Possible firefox version mismatch. You must use
> GeckoDriver instead for Firefox 48+. Profile Dir: /tmp/tmp9kciltry If
> you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it
> for details

this is how I initialise the webdriver: `webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary="/usr/bin/firefox", executable_path="/home/pi/src/geckodriver")`
`

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get it working by downgrading the geckodriver version from 0.27.0 to 0.23.0, I found a build over here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.23.0